# Slow extraction from a large raster, even after using crop to reduce size?

Tags: r, extract, raster

I have a large raster file (245295396) cells and stacks of rasters having 4 layers each which lie in the extent of this large raster. To start with, I am trying to get value from one stack (3 channels) and for the same zone from the large raster. Every things works fine, just the extraction from large raster takes 5 mins. So, if I repeat this process for 4000 more times it will take 13 days.

```
cld<- raster("cdl_30m_r_il_2014_albers.tif") #this is the large raster
r<- stack(paste(path,"/data_robin/", fl,sep="")) #1 stack,I have 4000 similar
mat<-as.data.frame(getValues(r)) # getting values from the stack
xy<-xyFromCell(r,c(1:ncell(r)),spatial = TRUE)
clip1 <- crop(cld, extent(r)) # Tried to crop it to a smaller size
cells<-cellFromXY(clip1,xy)
mat$landuse<- NA
# mat$landuse<-cld[cells]
mat$landuse<- extract(clip1,cells) #this line takes 5 mins based on profiling

> cld
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 20862, 11758, 245295396  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 378585, 731325, 1569045, 2194905  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /Users/kaswani/R/Image/cdl_30m_r_il_2014_albers.tif 
names       : cdl_30m_r_il_2014_albers 
values      : 0, 255  (min, max) 

> r
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 9230, 7502, 69243460, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.7995722, 0.7995722  (x, y)
extent      : 589084.4, 595082.8, 1564504, 1571884  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
names       : m_3608906_ne_16.1, m_3608906_ne_16.2, m_3608906_ne_16.3, m_3608906_ne_16.4 
min values  :                 0,                 0,                 0,                 0 
max values  :               255,               255,               255,               255
```

My data is in `.tiff` format and I am new to geospatial coding. Will really   appreciate any suggestions to improve the speed. I have also tried [this approach](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130522/r-increase-speed-of-crop-mask-extract-raster-by-many-polygons) but during the masking part it gives the error:

> Error in compareRaster(x, mask) : different extent.

Comment: I'm not well versed in processing raster files in R, but [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/extract-values-from-numerous-rasters-in-less-time/) is an article describing an alternative method of raster extraction that resulted in a > 40x improvement in processing time.

Comment: Duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156663/really-slow-extraction-from-raster-even-after-using-crop

Comment: Thanks, @scribbles, I am going through it. Will update here if it works.